# Is the existence of an uncountable proper subgroup of the real numbers under addition provable without AC?

Tags: group-theory, axiom-of-choice

With the axiom of choice, it is easy to show that there is an uncountable proper subgroup of the additive group of real numbers. Namely, if $H$ is a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then for any $x \in H$, the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ generated (or spanned) by $H \setminus \{x\}$ is an uncountable proper subgroup.

But, could an uncountable proper subgroup of the additive group of real numbers still be proven to exist without the axiom of choice?

Comment: Yes: in fact, it's possible to devise $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent subsets of $\Bbb R$ of cardinality $\beth_1$. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets/23206#23206) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35970/construction-of-a-proper-uncountable-subgroup-of-mathbbr-without-choice) on MO. In the first one, one of the answers suggests that there might even be subsets of $\Bbb R$ of cardinality $\beth_1$ that are provably algebraically independent in ZF (I did not check the articles, though).

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Re: definability, in fact we can do even better: there is a single formula which $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves defines a size-continuum set of reals $C$ no finite subset of which *computes* any other, which for examplies implies algebraic independency.